# How to re-use ZK session with KazooClient?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have different functions calling ZKNode and making changes to ZkPath. Currently, I am starting Zk (zk.start) session in each function and making zk.get / zk.stop. Is there a way to start one zk session and keep re-using same session until you are done?

```
from kazoo.client import KazooClient

zk_hosts = [ host1:2181, host2:2181, host3:2181]

def get_path_1(path):
    try:
       zk = KazooClient(hosts=zk_hosts, timeout=3000)
       zk.start()
    except Exception as e:
       log.fatal(e)
    if zk.exists(path):
       k = zk.get(path)
    else:
       print "ZK Path {0} does not exist".format(path)
    return k

def get_path_3(path2):
    try:
       zk = KazooClient(hosts=zk_hosts, timeout=3000)
       zk.start()
    except Exception as e:
       log.fatal(e)
    if zk.exists(path2):
       k = zk.get(path2)
    else:
       print "ZK Path {0} does not exist".format(path)
    return k
```

Comment: As far as I know, KazooClient is thread-safe. Share an instance.

Comment: an example would be appreciated.

Comment: posted it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

Since KazooClient is thread-safe, you could share the instance:

```
zk_hosts = [ host1:2181, host2:2181, host3:2181 ]

zk = KazooClient(hosts=zk_hosts, timeout=3000)
zk.start()

def get_path(path):
  if not zk.exists(path):
    print "ZK path {0} does not exist".format(path)
    return None

  return zk.get(path)

def get_already(path):
  return zk.get(path)
```

And so on.

As an advice, things can change between the `zk.exists` and the `zk.get` calls (for example, if someone else delete the entry). For this reason, you should test existence and get in a transaction.

Comment: BTW, transaction object is not thread-safe, so don't access one transaction instance in multi threads.